# Activiti: no signalEventReceived method

Tags: activiti

I've read [Activiti User Guide](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/) and [Activiti Forum](http://forums.activiti.org/content/start-subprocess-using-signal). And there to throw new event uses `signalEventReceived(String)` method of `RuntimeService`.

**Problem:**

There is no such method in `org.activiti.engine.RuntimeService`!

**My configurations:**

*pom.xml*

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
 <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
 <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
 <artifactId>activiti-spring</artifactId>
 <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  switch Activiti version to 5.13